# Pandas How to slice multiindex Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

```
           name                     address             contact_info    
        first_name  last_name       stret   city    mobile      email
    1   AAA             BBB         XXX     YYY     02020       aaa@xyz.com
    2   111             222         333     444     239393      bbb@xyz.com
```

I have an excel in the above format. What I want is to have every column inside **name** and then only **mobile** column inside **contact_info** would someone please let me know how I can do this. Following code gives me everything inside **name** and **contact_info**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", header=[0, 1], sheet_name="Mapping")
print df[["name", "contact_info"]]
```

I am trying to get something like this,

```
first_name  last_name   mobile
AAA         BBB        102020
111         222        239393
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to avoid concat, but this does it:

```
df = pd.read_excel("multi-index-test.xlsx", header=[0, 1], sheet_name="Mapping")
df.drop('address', level=0, axis=1).drop('e-mail', level=1, axis=1)
```

This takes advantage of [MultiIndex.drop()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.drop.html).

Answer (score 3):

By using `IndexSlice` + `concat`

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
pd.concat([df.loc[:, idx['name',:]],df.loc[:,idx[:,'mobile']]])
Out[104]: 
   contact_info       name          
         mobile first_name last_name
1           NaN        AAA       BBB
2           NaN        111       222
1          2020        NaN       NaN
2        239393        NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like concat cannot be avoided here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep , cause the multiple index

Answer (score 3):

You can use `df.xs` here:

```
i = df.xs('name', axis=1)
j = df.xs('mobile', axis=1, level=-1)

pd.concat([i, j], axis=1)

  first_name last_name  contact_info
1        AAA       BBB          2020
2        111       222        239393
```

Comment: is there any reason I could do without concat.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Simplest I could think of would be column slicing:

```
df['name'].join(df['contact_info']['mobile'])

  first_name last_name  mobile
1        AAA       BBB  020202
2        111       222  239393
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.DataFrame.filter`

```
df.filter(regex='name|mobile')

        name           contact_info
  first_name last_name       mobile
1        AAA       BBB       020202
2        111       222       239393
```

And we can drop the level

```
d = df.filter(regex='name|mobile')
d.columns = d.columns.droplevel(0)
d

  first_name last_name  mobile
1        AAA       BBB  020202
2        111       222  239393
```

Comment: Nice, the filter idiom is useful here, will commit to memory.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for just requires [basic indexing on a multiindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex) along with concat. Here's an example:

```
df = pd.read_excel("multi-index-test.xlsx", header=[0, 1])
df1 = df[["name"]]
df2 = df['contact_info', 'mobile']
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

I believe this solution has the benefit of being 1) simple and 2) general.